# JS Animate two properties (!JQ)

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome, animation

how to animate two properties in pure JavaScript (no JQuery)?
this doesn't work (only BG color gets animated):

```
element.animate([
  {transform: 'scale(1.6)', backgroundColor: '#FF0000'},
  {transform: 'scale(1)', backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF'}
], {
  duration: 1000,
  steps: 5,
  webkitAnimationTimingFunction: 'ease-out',\
});
```

works fine with just one (scale or bg color)

Comment: [Works for me](http://jsfiddle.net/mgbuf5xv/) (on Chrome 44), if I remove the typo (the backslash after `'ease-out',`). Both scale and background get animated.

Comment: Removed the [tag:google-chrome-extension] tag, since the issue is not extension-specific. Replaced with [tag:google-chrome].

Comment: @T.J.Crowder you are right...it works. But not always...I'm using [this page](http://get.geo.opera.com/pub/) for testing ...and works only with one property (links get either scaled or colored bg, but not both). I tested it on some other pages. Not all elements gets both animation.

Comment: @Xan should I remove question?

Comment: @WolfWar It's a fine question if you can find a reproductible case.

Comment: [this is how it looks on my side](https://youtu.be/-QYgbc75bk4) (in Opera, can't test it in Chrome, it is a sidebar extension). Some elements get both animations, and some only one... background color in this case. btw it's a links panel extension, like in old Opera Presto

Comment: ...but this is good enough. Not all elements should signal with scale

Answer (score -1):

You are trying to animate the same css property "backgroundColor",

The right code should be :

```
element.animate([
  {cssProperty: value0},
  {cssProperty: value1},
  {cssProperty: value2},
  //...
], {
    duration: timeInMs,
    iterations: iterationCount,
    delay: delayValue
});
```

But not the same property.

From : https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2014/05/Web-Animations---element-animate-is-now-in-Chrome-36